# Extract strings from string

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, string

Ill lose to much time since i don`t have too much experience in manipulating with strings/chars.

i have

```
string original = "1111,2222,"This is test work")";
```

i need

```
string first = "1111";
string second = "2222";
string name = "This is test work";
```

C# ASP.NET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`string.Split()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a) - your pattern is simple (split on comma), there is no need to use a RegEx here:

```
var parts = original.Split(',');
first = parts[0];
second = parts[1];
name = parts[2].TrimEnd(')'); //in case you really wanted to remove that last bracket
```

Comment: @AbeMiessler: Fortunately I *don't* have to since `string.Split` is using a `params char[] separator` as input - try it out.

Comment: +1, I stand corrected!  Could you explain what you mean by `params char[] separator`?

Comment: damn i forgot that i can use split :))). Thanks ! Solved

Comment: @Abe: A method that accepts a params array allows you to pass variable number of parameters separated by comma instead of an array, it it just syntactical sugar

Answer (score 1):

Use the [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) method:

```
string[] values = original.Split(new Char [] {','});
```

This will break apart your string at every comma and return a string array containing each part.  To access:

```
string first = values[0];
string second = values[1];
string name = values[2];
```